# If Statement in Power BI - Colors

Tags: if-statement

So I have a color statement but it is giving me back only Yellow and Red, but not green; I need green in the PASS -
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(ACTUALS)) ="FAIL", "RED" ,IF(SELECTEDVALUE(RECOVERABLES)) = "FALSE", "RED",
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(ACTUALS)) = "FAIL", "YELLOW", IF(SELECTEDVALUE(RECOVERABLES)) = "TRUE", "YELLOW",
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(ACTUALS)) = "PASS", "GREEN"

I am missing something, please help